# How to print all fields of structure in MASM32?

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, portable-executable, masm32

I am studying masm32 programming.
I am making a simple PE header reading program with masm32, I can print e_magic field's value(MZ) of IMAGE_DOS_HEADER structure.

```
invoke  dw2hex,dosHeader.e_lfanew,addr buffer
print   offset buffer
```

But I want to print all fields of this structure at a time.
How can I do this easily?
And 2nd question, how can I dump and print memory bytes of this structure like below?

```
0x00F1235A  68 eb 52 f1 00 e8 b5 ec ff ff 68 7d 54 f1 00 e8 ab  
0x00F1236B  ec ff ff 6a 40 ff 35 70 57 f1 00 68 00 50 f1 00 e8  
0x00F1237C  1e 01 00 00 66 81 3d 00 50 f1 00 4d 5a 74 10 68 46  
0x00F1238D  55 f1 00 e8 84 ec ff ff b8 01 00 00 00 c3 68 3c 50 
0x00F1239E  f1 00 e8 74 ec ff ff 68 c4 54 f1 00 e8 6a ec ff ff
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: In assembly language, you are programming directly to the CPU. You'll just have to print each member one at a time. And if you want to print memory bytes in a particular format, you write the code to print them in exactly the format you like. Maybe you can find a library to help with some of these things, but that's not something masm32 does for you.

Comment: There is no easy(convenient) way with MASM32 to print out each field in the structure, although I'd suggest maybe using the `crt_printf` function in MASM32 if you include `\masm32\include\masm32rt.inc`. There is a `printf` macro as well but that doesn't work the same as C `printf`. To get C like `printtf` you can use  `crt_printf` . This may also make creating a dump memory function easier.